# Preventing data-loss when deploying a new version of EF website?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, change-script

I'm building an ASP .NET MVC 4 application. Now, when I deploy a new version of this site to my live environment, I don't want to lose data just because my column names got renamed or something similar.

I'm using Entity Framework 4 to store objects in the database. Now, I am aware that this framework can generate so-called change-scripts. However, I do not trust them. Am I just being over-causious, or do I have reason not to trust them?

I'm designing the models in an EDMX diagram which then generates the tables for me. This makes it complicated for me to generate proper changescripts, especially when I do not (for sure) know how things are mapped into the database in certain scenarios.

So how do I get around this? If you use the same things as I do, what is your way of preventing data-loss on deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I probably have to wait for Entity Framework 5.

It seems that such a feature [is already planned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).